# PHP Write Code To File From Current Page On Click Of Button

Tags: php

**Goal**

What I'm aiming to achieve is to create a small web app where the user can edit certain elements such as img src, href, etc. Then save it to a file.

I've created the basic code which allows the user to edit however I'm struggling to take the amended code and save it to a .html file.

**Progress**

```
<?php 

function getHTMLByID($id, $html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $node = $dom->getElementById($id);
    if ($node) {
        return $dom->saveXML($node);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.mysql.com/');
$codeString = getHTMLByID('l1-nav-container', $html);
echo $codeString;

$myfile = fopen("newfile.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $codeString);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

I've created some basic code which saves a string to a file which is being received from another website however, I can't seem to work out how to get the code from the page.

Comment: Can you use the url of the file to get it's contents using `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: @AbhishekVAshok But then how do I track the changes and save them to the file?

Comment: Hi, not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but if you want to use php to store the contents of the page it has loaded you won't be able to. PHP is serve side it generates the html and quits by sending that html to browser where html is rendered. if you are trying to use the same call to capture your own page it won't work. Your best bet would be to read DOM on page with JS and them make an ajax call back to server sending the DOM info for storage.

Comment: @Auris I was hoping that triggering it via a button would allow the PHP to read the current page after the page has rendered.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how it works, php generates and then closes, it has no access to what happens on the browser. A button can be a link or a submit, but in any case it will start a new php process and your previous page will be lost. To send back entire DOM you either send it via ajax or load it in some hidden field and submit, but keep in mind that if your page is complex you will exceed the allowed request size

Comment: @Auris So your suggestion would to use AJAX to pass the data across to a php file save page? I'm sure I can find an example of how do this.

Comment: it would be one of the ways.

Comment: @Auris I just tired that I can meet the ajax data limit. Do you know of any other solutions I could look into?

Comment: Thing is data limit is set by server so no programming solution can change that. Your only option is to pick out DOM components that you need and send only them instead of the whole document

Comment: @Auris okey, I will try and work out a nice solution maybe send across the old data and new data, then do a simple php find and replace

Comment: You need other backend stuff as well as front end to do the things.